# Rsync over a Network

Tags: ssh, rsync

I can't exchange files between my pcs, when I give the command **sudo rsync -av -delete --rsh=ssh *localhost/directory* *remotehost/directory*** remotehost root password is required but when I type it the output is this: **root@remotehost's password: Permission denied, please try again**.

I don't know what's wrong, I type the exact password that I use when I type **su** (on the remotehost)

Please Help me

Edit: If I use a specific user (user@remotehost) I can transfer files, but I still haven't figured out why using root@remotehost doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you enter your local root password (the one you use for *su*). However, you show in your provided output that you are being asked for the *remote* root password.

```
root@remotehost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
```

Make sure you enter the root password for *remotehost*. If that fails, try running a

```
sudo ssh remotehost
```

And make sure that the ssh connection can open, before trying to run rsync through it. Maybe you need to tell it to accept a certificate first.

#### Conclusion

The inquisitor is running Linux Mint which disabled root user by default. Making a root user so that a "user@remotehost" exists is sufficient to get the rsync command working. http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Create-USER-with-ROOT-Privileges-in-Linux

Comment: Also worth noting, most installs these days disable root login, at least remotely. Try using a regular user account, not root.

Comment: You are right maybe I should have specified that when the root password for remotehost is asked what I type is remotehost root password

Comment: Ensure you can ssh to the remote root user. `ssh root@remotehost`. It is possible the `PermitRootLogin` option is set to *no* in the sshd_config file. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on the remote host.

Comment: I think I have figured out what's going on, read what I write and tell if what I say is wrong. I have linux mint installed on both the machine, but mint as default behaviour doesn't create root user, but instead only gives a user (thought su command) root privileges, if this is right what I have to do is to create a root user then I should be done

Comment: Yes, if you are certain you are ready to make a root user. Remember that there are reasons the packagers of Linux Mint decided to disable a root user. Rsyncing as root is not the best design ever, but here you go: http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Create-USER-with-ROOT-Privileges-in-Linux

Comment: I gotta thank you all, today I have learnt new things and solved my problems